# \power{n}{k} The power nk, but without \multiply

Tags: macros

How to do this using macros in TeX. Something like `\power{n}{k}` - the power of n to the value k - but without using `\multiply`.

Something like this needs to be done

```
k_{n+1} = n^2 + k_n^2 - k_{n-1}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question means. Please provide some code demonstrating what you want to achieve. Do you want to typeset a formula or calculate something with a macro?

Comment: A macros in TEX that compute The power nk, but without \multiply

Comment: If you'd try to do it yourself (using `\numexpr`) and show where you get stuck, you'd give people here something to start from. Or else, explain a little more about the context you need this for. The way you ask, it looks like you're asking people here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Why without `\multiply`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to work with integers, and e-TeX is available, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\power}[2]{%
  \the\numexpr\poweraux{#1}{#2}\relax
}
\newcommand*{\poweraux}[2]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#2 = 0 %
    \expandafter\powerend
  \else
    #1 * \expandafter\poweraux
  \fi
  {#1}{#2 - 1}%
}
\newcommand*{\powerend}[2]{1}
\begin{document}
\power{2}{3}
\end{document}
```

seems about right. I've not tested for edge cases or made this 'maximum efficiency' as I'm not entirely sure what is required.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) (or `pgfmath` from the [`pgf` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)) to produce floating point calculations without having to manually specify `\multiply`, `\divide`, or the like. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\begin{document}
\FPeval\result{round(3^4:0)}%
$3^4=​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​\result$
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

See the [`fp` README](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fp/README) for more information on the notation and usage.